# Ansible jinja templating trim last character

Tags: ansible, jinja2, trim

I want this output `ingress = ["aa","bb"]`

```
- name: Create the Jinja2 based template
  template:
    src: "/var/opt/conf.yml.j2"
    dest: "/var/opt/conf.yml"
  with_items: "{{ var }}"


ingress = [{% for item in var.stdout_lines %} "{{ item }}", {% endfor %}]
```

But I get this with a `,` at the end of the list

```
ingress = ["aa","bb",]
```

How could I trim the last character `,`

Comment: Since you are manually constructing a json representation, you'll want to `ingress = {{ var.stdout_lines | to_json`

Comment: You don't want to trim the last character, you want to output a list as json (or `join` its element for an other good solution proposed by @mdaniel). In your template => `ingress = {{ var.stdout_lines | to_json }}`. A last solution depending on your very exact requirement is to simply cast it as a string: `ingress = {{ var.stdout_lines | string }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for item in var.stdout_lines %} "{{ item }}" {%if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That does work, but that's a lot of code to a simply transform a list into a json representation.

Comment: @Zeitounator True, but there are other use cases.  Mine was `workers.properties` for an apache load balancer.

Comment: 1) If you are not outputting a json representation of a list, you are not answering OP's question. 2) if you do need only the sting within the brackets of the json representation, there is still a better solution: => `"{{ var.stdout_lines | join('","') }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator The OP's question was, "How [could I] trim the last character[?]".

Comment: True, but his requirement is clearly => I want to output `ingress = ["aa","bb"]`. This makes it very easy to spot he is in an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and the answer should IMO be given accordingly.

Comment: @Zeitounator True, but that could have been only an example.  He asked a generic question, so I provided a generic answer.